# Render Object Mode Optics

Tags: rendering, object-mode

Is it possible at all to render an animation (image sequence or video) in the object mode?

So that you can only see the skeleton of the 3D models?

Thanks! D.

Comment: Every animation is rendered in _Object Mode_ (as opposed to _Edit Mode_, _Weight Paint_ etc.) if you use Ctrl+F12, the "normal" render. I guess what you mean is rendering the viewport display. Oh, I see @Chris already posted an answer for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

Click on View -> Render viewport animation

[image]